# Having trouble with regex to match specific number pattern

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I am struggling trying to write a regex to match a pattern that looks for repeated digits in a string like

`123445678` or `1234 45678`
In this case the 4's would be repeated even though there is a space in the second case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Another `grep` solution:

```
egrep '([0-9]) *\1'
```

Proof of concept:

```
$ echo 1234 45678 | egrep -o '([0-9]) *\1'
4 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if there is a more elegant way to do this, but the following works:

```
egrep --color "0 *0|1 *1|2 *2|3 *3|4 *4|5 *5|6 *6|7 *7|8 *8|9 *9" <<< "1234 45678"
```

Matches: 123**4 4**5678

Comment: Worked perfectly for what I needed to do.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You use a back reference to a capture group:

```
(\d).*\1
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iE7cP8/1)

If you want the match to only be if there is a space between (no other digits or character) you can do:

```
(\d)[ ]*\1
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iE7cP8/2)

Which works in `egrep` too:

```
$ echo 1234 45678 | egrep --color '(\d)[ ]*\1' 
1234 45678
```

And Posix:

```
$ echo 1234 45678 | egrep '([[:digit:]])[[:blank:]]*\1' 
1234 45678
```

Comment: This doesn't work: `egrep --color '(\d)[ ]*\1'`, since `\d` is PCRE syntax, not ERE.

Comment: GNU grep it does work. That is also why I gave the [POSIX alternative character classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes) that is supported by BRE, ERE and PCRE by non=GNU grep, awk, sed, etc. If you are worried about non-POSIX regular expressions, then parenthesis need to be escaped in SRE `\([0-9]\)` or it is a literal parenthesis. But SRE has been deprecated for more than 20 years...

Comment: `grep` uses BRE, basic regular expressions.  `egrep` uses extended regular expressions, ERE.  To this day, neither has been deprecated.  GNU `grep` accepts PCRE patterns only if you pass it the `-P` option.  `\d` is PCRE syntax, and GNU `grep` version 2.21 doesn't accept it:  `echo 1234 45678 | egrep --color '(\d)[ ]*\1'` doesn't return anything on my machine.